# Location Services Fails on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, gps, location, galaxy

I have problems working, and debugging my App only on Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

It was upgraded via OTA last week to Android 4.4.2

The LogCat throws many errors from LocSvc_utils_q , LocSvc_11, LocSvc_ApiV02 and so on. Hundreds of messages per second, which flush the real messages intended to debug.

```
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(838): D/virtual void LocApiV02::eventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType):2663]: event id = 38
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_utils_q(838): D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x794AD618
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_utils_ll(838): D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 0x794AD618
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_utils_q(838): D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x794AD618
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_utils_q(838): D/msg_q_snd: Sending message with handle = 0x77E743D0
09-09 14:28:14.735: E/LocSvc_utils_ll(838): D/linked_list_add: Adding to list data_obj = 0x77E743D0
09-09 14:28:14.745: E/LocSvc_utils_q(838): D/msg_q_snd: Finished Sending message with handle = 0x77E743D0
09-09 14:28:14.745: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(838): D/void LocApiV02::reportNmea(const qmiLocEventNmeaIndMsgT_v02*):2354]: $GSV
09-09 14:28:14.745: E/LocSvc_ApiV02(838): I/<--- void globalEventCb(locClientHandleType, uint32_t, locClientEventIndUnionType, void*) line 88 QMI_LOC_EVENT_NMEA_IND_V02

09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/num sv: 20
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   ephemeris mask: 1412858048xn  almanac mask: 543680c0
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   used in fix mask: 0
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):       sv: prn         snr       elevation      azimuth
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   0:   7    0.000000    7.000000    324.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   1:   8    0.000000    12.000000    322.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   2:   16    0.000000    78.000000    307.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   3:   18    0.000000    35.000000    99.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   4:   19    0.000000    23.000000    277.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   5:   21    0.000000    47.000000    52.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   6:   22    0.000000    26.000000    146.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   7:   27    0.000000    51.000000    298.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   8:   29    0.000000    1.000000    82.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   9:   31    0.000000    5.000000    185.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   10:   78    0.000000    4.000000    177.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   11:   66    0.000000    24.000000    97.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   12:   82    0.000000    46.000000    292.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   13:   73    0.000000    7.000000    336.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   14:   80    0.000000    46.000000    300.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   15:   79    0.000000    44.000000    209.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   16:   65    0.000000    18.000000    42.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   17:   88    0.000000    7.000000    63.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   18:   81    0.000000    51.000000    25.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838): D/   19:   67    0.000000    4.000000    144.000000
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_eng(838):   
09-09 14:28:14.755: E/LocSvc_afw(838): I/<=== sv_status_cb - line 1262 20
```

I couldn't find definitive information of how to deal with it. Same code Worked for a Nexus 7 and other devices.

Does anyone know something about it?